# How to simulate an RF power source in LTSpice?

Tags: rf, ltspice

I am testing out an RF power amplifier that I have designed in LTSpice. How do I model the input RF power source to the amplifier in LTSpice?

Comment: RF source is no different from any other voltage/current source, just frequency is higher.

Comment: yeah use an AC source with a series resistor.to set impedance.

Comment: Sources in SPICE have a internal impedance that you can set to whatever impedance your source should have. You can then use some basic math to find the voltage/current needed (depends if you want to use a current or voltage source) from the power

Comment: Are you aware that although you can model the equivalent circuit in ltspice, you need to be very careful about keeping that circuit equivalent? For example, if your amplifier has an output wave impedance of 50 ohms at 100 MHz it's almost certain that's not the case at 1 GHz. Also, you need to be a bit careful about aspects of resistance vs wave impedance, since a 50 ohm transmission line doesn't have a resistance of 50 ohm - it's just a representation of the relationship between H- and E-Field in that line, and you must, for matched transmission, model both in- and output as 50 ohm resistances

Comment: ... But that doesn't mean anything in that converts electrical energy to heat like 50 ohm resistors would. In that sense, I'd be very careful with @AliChen's "is no different": if you know how to model things so that these are representable by spice components, then that's true. The difference lies in the need to know how to model circuits. Also, for RF, the difference between "this looks fine as a schematic" and "this can actually be built" is much larger than for low-frequency electronics.